# Show picture upon cell selection that matches cell string to picture database in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I will attempt to explain to the best of my abilities what I am looking for as far as a final product. I am trying to make a spreadsheet that has a list of strings in a column.

When the strings are hovered over, the string will be used to match to the name of a picture in a database. The database will return the picture and show it as a rollover image.

I have searched for ways on how to do this, but I keep finding people who change it based on the comments and use a static image for each cell. I have a database of around 23000 pictures and can't do it manually one at a time, and the cells have the potential to be variable depending on the opened sheets.

Hover over is not necessary, however. I would be more than happy to do this upon a cell selection.

Comment: There's an event handler `Worksheet_SelectionChange` you can use for this: start there and post back with code when you run into problems.

Comment: What kind of DBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question and covers many parts.  Here is a little something to get you started.

Open the VB Editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.  Right click on the sheet you want this functionality to exist on and then click View Code.  This code will load a comment with a single image (be sure to change `C:\YOUR_IMAGE_FULL_PATH` to a valid image) into whichever cell you click into.  When you leave the cell it will delete the comment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        Static cellAddress
        Dim sFile As String
        Dim cmt As Comment

        If cellAddress <> "" Then
            Set cmt = Range(cellAddress).Comment
            cmt.Delete
            Set cmt = Nothing
        End If

        sFile = "C:\YOUR_IMAGE_FULL_PATH"

        Set cmt = Target.AddComment
        cmt.Text Text:=""
        With cmt.Shape
            .Fill.UserPicture sFile
        End With

        cellAddress = Target.Address

    End If

End Sub
```

When you say

> The database will return the picture and show it as a rollover image

Does that mean the image itself is stored in the database?  Or is the name of the image returned from the database and we have to search a directory on the HDD for an image with that name?

Without knowing your DBMS or your table schema or anything like that I can't really help much more.